# options on a jsp page

Tags: html, postgresql

I have a jsp page which takes options from 2 different tables in a postgres database.

```
<form method="post">
<label for="acc_Name">Account Name/Project Name:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <select>
    <%  while(resultset.next()){ %>
        <option><%=  resultset.getString(1)+"/"+resultset.getString(2)%></option>
    <% } %>
    </select> <br />
```

Here, resultset.getString(1) is the account name whereas resultset.getString(2) is the project name. I need to run a query wherein I will be needing the account name from the selected option.
For instance, my query would be : Select account_id from Account where account_name=account name from the selected option.
How can I achieve this in HTML? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: My feeling is that most of these things should happen in a controller and not in the view.